# Symfony 4 collection type transformer. How to elegantly display the values in a text field?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm working with symfony 4. I have a ManyToMany relationship(surprisingly not that relevant to the question) featuring a junction table. Lets say entity A can have many entity B and vice versa. Lets also assume that A owns B.

I have built a form that looks like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('B', TextType::class, [
        'invalid_message' => 'Some invalid message',
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'tags',
        ]
    ])
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class);

$builder->get('B')
    ->addModelTransformer($this->transformer)
;
```

Next I have the transformer:

```
public function transform($bunchOfB_s)
{
    // returns json_encode
}


public function reverseTransform($bunchOfB_s)
{
    // json_decode and transform to B entity
}
```

I couldn't find a decent solution as to NOT render each B separately.

The problem is in the html itself. Currently it looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group"><label for="admin_video_tags" class="required">Tags</label><input type="text" id="admin_video_tags" name="admin_video[tags]" required="required" class="tags form-control ui-autocomplete-input" value="[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;tag_ 6&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:47},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;tag_ 7&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:48},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;tag_ 16&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:57}]" autocomplete="off"></div>
```

[image]

I want to use an autocomplete via some jquery plugin or something. I don't need to do an ajax call since there are only about 15 total values for this field. I can simply pass them to the view when I render it.

I can use javascript to clear the field.

However, that doesn't strike me as an elegant solution. It's more of a hack.

Ideally, I'm looking for something more elegant.

Honestly not sure what. I'm hoping somebody who knows their way better around symfony 4 can lend a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are asking for but it is a more elegant solution using check boxes or a select to choose multiple `B` entities with one input (I don't believe you need a transformer with this). This will allow only existing `B`'s to be entered.

```
use App\Entity\B;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
// ...

$builder->add('B', EntityType::class, [
    // looks for choices from this entity
    'class' => B::class,

    // function to get the B's you want as choices
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->orderBy('b.name', 'ASC');
    },

    // uses the B.name property as the visible option string
    'choice_label' => 'name',

    // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
    // both true for checkboxes
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    // for select
    'expanded' => false,
]);
```

Another way (but much more work), using a single text input for each `B` is to first create a formType for `B` with the `TextType::class`. Then in AType form use a `CollectionType::class` for adding `B`'s to `A`. This method requires some javascript to add rows to the collection but this would create new `B`'s within the AType form, and not use existing (without more javascript).

```
$builder->add('B', CollectionType::class, [
    // each entry in the array will be a "B" field
    'entry_type' => B::class,

]);
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html